# Why are mouse events from my directive not reflected in the view?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

Here is an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jer2/6zbKP/3/).  Please open the console first.

It's a little long, so to quickly explain:  You'll see two divs.  One is "regular", the other is created via a directive.  They both have click event handlers (added via ng-click).

Clicking the regular (non-directive) div does what I expect - the appropriate variables in the scope are set and you see that in the view (top two lines in the output show the id and top of the div that was clicked).

The problem is when clicking the directive div.  These variables are not updated.  I know I'm misunderstanding something about the scope of the directive, but what is confusing me is the log messages that are printed (open the console when you do this).  The clicks are registered, and the controller's scope *does* set the variable values, as you can see in the console.

Yet the html does not update - try clicking one div, then the other, and go back and forth, and you'll see.

What am I missing here?

Code (please don't be put off by its length!):

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">

        Top of the div you just clicked = {{top}}.<br/>
        Id of the div you just clicked = {{lastId}}.<br/>

        <div id="notADirective" class="myClass" ng-click="update($event)">
            Not a directive.  Click me.
        </div>

        <my-div element-id="isADirective" cls="myClass">
            I'm a directive.  Click me.
        </my-div>

</div>


angular.module('components', [])
    .controller('MyController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.lastId = '';
    $scope.top = '';

    $scope.update = function (event) {
        var myDiv = getFirstMyClassAncestor(event.target);
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(myDiv);
        $scope.top = style.top;
        $scope.lastId = myDiv.id;
        console.log("You just clicked " + $scope.lastId + " and its top is " + $scope.top);
    }

    function getFirstMyClassAncestor(element) {
        while (element.className.indexOf('myClass') < 0) {
            element = element.parentNode;
        }
        return element;
    }


}).directive('myDiv', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        controller: 'MyController',
        scope: {
            cls: '@',
            elementId: '@'
        },

        template: '<div id="{{elementId}}" class="{{cls}}" ng-click="update($event)"><div ng-transclude></div></div>'
    }
});

angular.module('MyApp', ['components'])

.myClass {
    background-color: #DA0000;
    position: absolute;
}
#isADirective {
    top: 300px;
}
#notADirective {
    top: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of your directive the assigned controller `MyController` gets the scope of this directive and not the scope of `div` as you probably expect. I added a log statement for the different scope ids:

http://jsfiddle.net/6zbKP/4/

If you want to update the outer or parent scope you have to use a binding like this:

```
scope: {
        cls: '@',
        elementId: '@',
        callback: '='
},
```

Then bind your update function in the directive:

```
<my-div element-id="isADirective" cls="myClass" callback="update">
    I'm a directive.  Click me.
</my-div>
```

And call the callback in your directive:

```
 template: '<div id="{{elementId}}" class="{{cls}}" ng-click="callback($event)"><div ng-transclude></div></div>'
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/6zbKP/5/

Comment: Thank you!  This is starting to make more sense, and great tip to log $scope.$id.   Only thing - the main point of my directive (the real one, not this example) is to make the html file much more terse.  The directive's div (and sub-divs) actually have 8 mouse listeners on it - it is basically a window that can be resized, maximized, dragged around, closed, etc. - do I really need to add all the mouse event functions as attributes in the directive (like you did with `callback="update"`)?  This clutters up the html and logically doesn't seem to add anything (just maps one function to another).

Answer (score 0):

The angular expression bindings are outside of your directive's isolated scope. And you haven't imported lastId or top from your parent controller scope into your directives isolated scope, so there is no reason to expect that updating one variable in the inner directive scope will update the variable in the outer controller scope. There is no two way binding set up.

You can setup two way binding however using scope: {lastId: '=', top: '=' }.

Also you shouldn't be sharing controllers like you're doing.  I suggest using anonymous controller functions.

Comment: What's the downside to passing the name of the controller to the directive like this?  In my real application, the controller analogous to MyController here is pretty huge - I definitely can't define it within the directive definition.

Comment: I was playing with your fiddle, and there was definitely weirdness, which was resolved by separating out your controllers.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with defining your controller functions externally. I think you may run into issues if you share them like you have in your fiddle.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused then - what exactly do you mean by "sharing" them?

Comment: You defined ng-view using routes with a controller, and then defined a directive that uses the same controller. Both are sharing the same controller in the same SPA